# Ninject Di bindings using a WCF service

Tags: wcf, ninject, ninject-extensions

I recently created a WCF service library. I am planning on hosting it in IIS. Since I want to reuse my repository layer I decided to go use Ninject in my WCF service as well (I use it in other projects in the solution).

I installed the Ninject Wcf Extensions. I configured it using the NinjectServiceHostFactory in the svc file. I added a Global.asax file to override the CreateKernel() that inherits from NinjectWcfApplication but I am not sure if I am using the bindings correctly. I first started with:

```
Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InRequestScope();
```

But I quickly realized that this does not work since no data was saved to my database. It appears that the WCF service does not use the ASP.NET pipeline. I went ahead and tried both of these as well just to see if my data was committed to the database:

```
Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InThreadScope();
Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InTransientScope();
```

No luck. I then decided to try:

```
Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InSingletonScope();
```

This worked but I don't want my database context to be shared by every single request that comes in to the WCF service. I then did some research and found the following approach:

```
Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InScope(c => OperationContext.Current);
```

This works but is it correct? I wan t something to resemble the InRequestScope for a MVC application. Each request to the service should get its own Database context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to have a look at the latest build from the CI-Server http://teamcity.codebetter.com

You need Ninject, Ninject.Web.Common, Ninject.Extensions.Wcf

With this version you can use InRequestScope for Wcf.

Comment: Thanks Remo, I will take a look. But assume I just want to use Ninject and Ninject.Extensions.Wcf, would OperationContext.Current be something you suggest using as scope. Especially if I would want to move the WCF service to a non IIS host down the line.

Comment: Probably you missunderstood. You will have to do this soon anyway if you want to use the latest version of Ninject. Web.cmmon is a required dependency for the wcf extension even if self hosted.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to Ninject, but I can tell you that `OperationContext.Current` is the equivalent to `HttpContext.Current` for web application.

So your first thought was to use `.InRequestScope();` (which is equivalent to `.InScope(c => HttpContext.Current);`)

so I guess that using `.InScope(c => OperationContext.Current);` for WCF is pretty correct.

Comment: Nothing really wrong with this, just wanted to point out there's also a mode in WCF, where it piggybacks onto a `HttpContext.Current`, though in general `OperationContext.Current` is right. Note that @Remo Gloor's recommendation is the way to go  as it wraps this stuff up, dealing cleanly with scenarios like mixed WCF/Web apps, regardless of whether you've told WCF to create a HttpContext or not (as opposed to maintaining two completely different contexts).